# Restoring Fiori Application State

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am developing a Fiori (SAPUI5) Application with multiple views.
First view contains a Smart Filter Bar with a Smart Table.

What I want to archive is the following:
User enters search values in the smart filter bar and these values should be restore after the page is reloaded.

I followed that tutorial and was able to save and restore the app state (filter values) when navigation to another view. But unfortunately I am not able to restore the values after page is reloaded.

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/06/19/restoring-fiori-application-state/

Does anyone know if this is even possible with the iapp state or if I need another approach like Session, Cookie etc?

Comment: are you using an abap system? you could use the built-in tools if so. it uses the "persistencyKey" properties on the smart table and smart filter

Comment: As far as I know the PersistencyKey is for the purpose of saving the different variants only?

Comment: That’s what a variant is. It stores filters and layout etc as well. Or so you want to store the values themselves?

Comment: I want to store the values in the different smart filter bar input fields, but not permanent, but rather for the case the user clicks on F5 and reloads the page